# Logstash missing config

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I have following issue . Every time when I'm trying to set config for logstash it doesn't see my file. I am sure that the path is properly set.
There is info:

```
[2018-09-14T09:28:44,073][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"/home/jakub/IdeaProjects/test/logstash.conf"}
```

My docker-compose.yml looks following:

```
  logstash:
image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.4.0
networks: ['stack']
ports:
- "9290:9290"
- "4560:4560"
command: logstash -f /home/jakub/IdeaProjects/test/logstash.conf
depends_on: ['elasticsearch']
```

and logstash.conf:

```
    input {
  redis {
    host => "redis"
    key => "log4j2"
    data_type => "list"
    password => "RedisTest"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "elasticsearch"
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Can you give me some advice or solve my issue ?
Thanks for everything.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your logstash.conf is on your host under /home/jakub/IdeaProjects/test/logstash.conf.

Thus, it is not inside your container (unless there is some hidden mount). The command will be executed from within the container, thus it points to a non-existing file.

So, you may use docker cp /home/jakub/IdeaProjects/test/logstash.conf :/home/jakub/IdeaProjects/test/logstash.conf (provided the directory exists in your container)

... or (better!) mount the path from your host to your container. Such as :

```
volumes:
  - /home/jakub/IdeaProjects/test/logstash.conf:/home/jakub/IdeaProjects/test/logstash.conf:ro
```

.. or to use [config](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/#defining-and-using-configs-in-compose-files) (the best option to moo if you are in swarm mode!). The mount is close to the "volume"  option above, but you also have to pre-create (from command line or from docker-compose file)

There are other options, but the main point is that **you have to make your file available from within your container**!